Performance of mamba vs conda
I was thinking about mamba, the drop-in replacement of conda, and I was curious to benchmark the precise gains in performance with respect to conda in an environment as free as possible from external variables.
Setup
I set up a live USB Linux environment (EndeavourOS, an Arch-based distro), and once I done the test with conda (miniconda) I rebooted the system and repeated the test with mamba (miniforge). My internet connection was wired (no WiFi) and I ran a speedtest before every install command, to make sure that the internet speed was constant: it was, and the values oscillated within ± 3 Mbps.
Procedure for conda

Download miniconda from this page
Check the hash (was ok)
Install miniconda with $ bash <file>.sh and close-reopen the terminal
Since is not recommended to use mamba with the channel defaults, add conda-forge with $ conda config --add channels conda-forge, disable defaults with $ conda config --remove channels defaults and check everything went well with $ conda config --show channels and $ conda config --get channels
Create a new environment with $ conda create --name testconda, close conda with $ conda deactivate, activate new environment with $ conda activate testconda
Install the classic data science packages with $ conda install python=3.10.6 numpy=1.21.5 pandas=1.3.5 matplotlib=3.5.1 jupyterlab; I specified some particular versions of them to make the solving process more complicated.
Export the list of packages and their versions with conda list.

Procedure for mamba

Download miniforge from this page
Check the hash (was ok)
Install miniforge with $ bash <file>.sh and close-reopen the terminal
Check that the only active channel is conda-forge with $ conda config --show channels and $ conda config --get channels
Create a new environment with $ mamba create --name testmamba, close mamba with $ mamba deactivate, activate new environment with $ mamba activate testmamba
Install the same data science packages with $ mamba install python=3.10.6 numpy=1.21.5 pandas=1.3.5 matplotlib=3.5.1 jupyterlab.
Compare the list of packages and their versions with the one created with conda to see if they are the same (they were, indeed).

Results
I've repeated those protocols three times for each of the two tools and I've taken note of the time (rounded to the nearest second) required by the main steps; the results were the same for the three iterations of each tool (this level of reproducibility surprised me, btw).




Conda
Mamba




Install miniconda/miniforge
5 s
4 s


Create the environment
17 s
3 s


Download and install the packages
1 m 39 s
1 m 43 s



At first I was surprised that conda was so fast at the "solving environment" phase, but I quickly realized that now the default solver is libmamba (conda config --show solver), so this easily explained the speed at this specific task. I also checked the packages list in the base environments and I confirm that mamba is present only in the miniforge installation.
Questions
Now my main question is: what are the components substituted in the miniforge distribution?
In particular:

The creating environment task is clearly faster with mamba, so I suppose that the software component for this task has been entirely rewritten in C++ and this is the reason for the speed difference. Will they eventually rewrite all the other components in C++, thus allowing to write only mamba <option> and never conda <option>?
The download and install task has been faster in the miniconda test: why? In know that 4 seconds means nothing in everyday life, in fact mine is a simple curiosity.

In the first lines of the README mamba claims to have an advantage specifically in the download task ("parallel downloading of repository data and package files using multi-threading"); so I suppose that this code has been implemented even in the classic miniconda distribution?
My only hypothesis for the slower whole process in mamba/miniforge is that the terminal UI of this one (more "modern" and colored) is heavier on the computer resources... but I acknowledge that it's a weak idea and even my PC is very modern, so it's unlikely that it's a problem for the CPU.




If you'd like to make this more rigorous, keep all the repeat trial numbers rather than summarizing them and report standard deviations, possibly run a statistical test. For practical purposes I regard them as equivalent performance-wise these days (Conda caught up), though Conda has added some advanced index caching that only the defaults channels support. On the other hand, the bigger consideration for many users is that Anaconda (which distributes Miniconda) requires paid licensing for commercial use, including any use of defaults channels; Conda Forge and Miniforge remain free.
